# Blackberry APplication not rendering well on PORSCHE phones

Tags: user-interface, blackberry

I have got a Blackberry native application I have been working on in the past few weeks. 
Basically it consists of a few screens in which I get to draw the designs of my screen by overriding the paint method of the FieldManagers 
I have tested on blackberry 4.5 and other blackberry's.
It has rendered well so far until I ran into a hitch testing on Blackberry's Porsche version
which does not render my designs well. What I experience is that on scrolling, my screen gets wiped off.
Pls does any one here experienced such issues in the past and what would be the cause. I would be willing to show sections of the code to give insight into the issues I am experiencing. Least I mention it displays well on the simulator without these issues.

I have posted a sample screen which is my login screen:

```
final VerticalFieldManager everythingPanel = new VerticalFieldManager(VERTICAL_SCROLL)
    {
        public void paint(Graphics graphics)
        {
            graphics.setBackgroundColor(new UtilNew().ashbrand);
            graphics.clear();
            super.paint(graphics);
        }
        public void sublayout(int width, int height){

            super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight());
            setExtent(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
        }
    };


    final VerticalFieldManager spaceHolder1 = new VerticalFieldManager()
    {
        public void paint(Graphics graphics)
        {
            graphics.setBackgroundColor(new Util().ashbrand);
            graphics.clear();
            super.paint(graphics);
        }


        public void sublayout(int width, int height){
            super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(),topSpaceHeight);
            setExtent(Display.getWidth(), topSpaceHeight);
        }
    };




    final VerticalFieldManager contentHolderPix = new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL)
    {
        public void paint(Graphics graphics)
        {


            graphics.setBackgroundColor(util.ashbrand);//black
            graphics.setColor(new Util().whitebrand);
            System.out.println(">>>>!!!!>>>>" + "img/icons/logo" + new Util().getResource() + ".png");
            EncodedImage image_1 = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("img/icons/icon" + new Util().getResource() + ".png");

            setFont(util.initializeUtilFont("Arial", editFieldFontHeaderSize, Font.BOLD));
            int startHere = topSpaceHeight - image_1.getHeight() - 5;
            int imageWidth1 = (int)((Display.getWidth() - image_1.getWidth() - getFont().getAdvance("Sign In"))/2);
            graphics.drawBitmap(new XYRect(imageWidth1 - 10 - whiteBgEdge.left - whiteBgEdge.right, startHere, image_1.getWidth(), image_1.getHeight()), image_1.getBitmap(), 0, 0);
            int startfonty = startHere + ((image_1.getHeight() - getFont().getHeight())/2);

            graphics.drawText("Sign In", imageWidth1, startfonty);
            super.paint(graphics);

        }


        public void sublayout(int width, int height){
            super.sublayout(whiteBgWidth,topSpaceHeight);
            setExtent(whiteBgWidth, topSpaceHeight);
            setMargin(whiteBgEdge);
        }
    };



    System.out.println("whiteBgWidth>>>>" + whiteBgWidth); 
    System.out.println("padExtWhiteBg>>>>" + padExtWhiteBg);


    usernameField = utilNew.newEditTextField(editFieldWidth, editFont.getHeight(), 30, 
            EditField.NO_NEWLINE, "", editFieldPad, editFont, false, "Username");
    passwordField = utilNew.newPasswordField(editFieldWidth, editFont.getHeight(), 30, 
            PasswordEditField.NO_NEWLINE,       "Password", editFieldPad, editFont);
    //usernameField.setMargin(holderPad1);
    if(user_!=null && user_.getSignInUserName()!=null && user_.getSignInUserName().trim().length()>0)
        usernameField.setText(user_.getSignInUserName());

    final int edHt = editFont.getHeight() + editFieldPad.top + editFieldPad.bottom;
    final int edWt = editFieldWidth +  editFieldPad.left + editFieldPad.right;
    System.out.println("edHt = " + edHt);
    System.out.println("edWt = " + edWt);
    System.out.println("HolderPad1 = " + holderPad1.top + ",  " + holderPad1.bottom + ",  " + holderPad1.left + ",  " + holderPad1.right);
    usernameFieldHolder = utilNew.generateEditTextField(usernameField, true, holderPad1, edHt, edWt, true);
    passwordFieldHolder = utilNew.generateEditTextField(passwordField, true, holderPad2, edHt, edWt, false);


    final int height_ = edHt + edHt + holderPad1.top + holderPad1.bottom + holderPad2.top + holderPad2.bottom + 20;
    System.out.println("height___>>>>>" + height_);


    final VerticalFieldManager contentHolder1 = new VerticalFieldManager()
    {
        public void paint(Graphics graphics)
        {


            //System.out.println(edHt + "," + edHt + "," + holderPad1.top + "," + holderPad1.bottom + "," + holderPad2.top + "," + holderPad2.bottom);
            graphics.setBackgroundColor(util.ashbrand);//black

            graphics.setColor(new Util().whitebrand);
            graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, whiteBgWidth, height_, 20, 20);
            graphics.fillRoundRect(0, 0, whiteBgWidth, height_, 20, 20);
            graphics.setColor(0x00808080);
            //System.out.println("This is changed?");
            //System.out.println("<<<<<<.." + usernameFieldHolder.getPreferredHeight() + "hfm.getPreferredHeight() = 0" + usernameFieldHolder.getWidth() );
            //graphics.drawLine(40, usernameField.getPreferredHeight(), whiteBgWidth, usernameField.getPreferredHeight());/**/
            super.paint(graphics);

        }


        public void sublayout(int width, int height){

            System.out.println(Display.getHeight()  + " - " + Display.getWidth());
            System.out.println("Wdith & height = " + width  + " && " + height);
            System.out.println("Wdith & this.getPreferredHeight() = " + this.getWidth()  + " && " + this.getHeight());
            super.sublayout(whiteBgWidth,height_);
            setExtent(whiteBgWidth, height_);
            setMargin(whiteBgEdge);
        }
    };


    int buttonHeight = 70;

    /*CustomManager hfm_buttons = util.generateHFM1(
            contentHolder1.getPreferredWidth(), 
            buttonHeight, 
            new Util().whitebrand,
            0);*/
    //submitButton = new UtilNew().generateButtonField(0x333333, util.whitebrand,   "LOGIN", null);
    //registerButton = new UtilNew().generateButtonField(0x333333, util.whitebrand,     "REGISTER", null);


    final LabelField loginButton = new LabelField("", Field.FOCUSABLE)
    {

        private int hColor;

        public boolean isFocusable() {
            return true;
        }

        protected void drawFocus(Graphics g, boolean on){
            XYRect rect = new XYRect();
            getFocusRect(rect);
            drawHighlightRegion(g, HIGHLIGHT_FOCUS, false, rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
        }


        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            EncodedImage left;
            EncodedImage right;
            EncodedImage center;

            if(isFocus())
            {
                left = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("img/buttons/left.png");
                center = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("img/buttons/center.png");
                right = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("img/buttons/right.png");
                g.setColor(util.green);
                hColor = 0xcccccc;
            }
            else
            {
                left = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("img/buttons/_left.png");
                center = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("img/buttons/_center.png");
                right = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("img/buttons/_right.png");
                g.setColor(util.greenDark);
                hColor = util.ashbrand;
            }
            //g.fillRect(0, 0, getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
            int totalWidth = whiteBgWidth + 4;
            XYRect left_edge=new XYRect(2, 2, left.getWidth(), left.getHeight());


            g.drawBitmap(left_edge, left.getBitmap(), 0, 0);
            //invalidate();
            int startX= (Display.getWidth() - totalWidth)/2;
            int vount = (int)((totalWidth - left.getWidth() - right.getWidth())/center.getWidth()) - 3;
            //System.out.println("vount = " + vount);
            int widthbt = 0;
            for(int c=0; c<vount; c++)
            {
                widthbt = left.getWidth() + (c*center.getWidth())+2;
                XYRect center_edge=new XYRect(widthbt, 2, center.getWidth(), center.getHeight());
                g.drawBitmap(center_edge, center.getBitmap(), 0, 0);
            }
            XYRect right_edge=new XYRect(widthbt,2, right.getWidth(), right.getHeight());
            g.drawBitmap(right_edge, right.getBitmap(), 0, 0);
            //invalidate();
            //g.drawBitmap(right_edge, right.getBitmap(), 0, 0);
            //g.fillRect(left_edge.getWidth(), 0, getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
            int colorOld = g.getColor();
            g.setColor(hColor);
            g.drawRoundRect(0, 0, totalWidth-4, left.getHeight()+4, 3, 3);
            g.setColor(colorOld);

            if(isFocus())
            {
                g.setColor(util.black);
            }
            else
            {
                g.setColor(util.whitebrand);
            }

            int height = (left.getHeight() - getFont().getHeight())/2;
            int width = (totalWidth - getFont().getAdvance("Sign In"))/2;
            g.drawText("Sign In", width, height);
            setExtent(totalWidth+ 5,left.getHeight() + 10);
            //setMargin(new XYEdges(20, 10, 0, whiteBgEdge.left));
            invalidate();
            super.paint(g);
        }

        public int getPreferredHeight() {
            return getFont().getHeight() + 20;
        }

        public int getPreferredWidth() {
            return (int)(whiteBgWidth);
        }

        protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {

            removeAllMenuItems();
            String userName = usernameField.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
            user_.setSignInUserName(userName);
            String passWord = passwordField.getText().toString();
            System.out.println("username = " + userName + " & password = " + passWord);
            User user = User.getInstance();
            System.out.println(">>instance of user from sign in: " + user);
            Records record = new Records();

            if(passWord.trim().length() < 2 || userName.trim().length() < 2){
                Dialog.alert("Invalid username and/or password entered");
                SignIn screen = new SignIn();
                ScreenController screenController = ScreenController.getInstance();
                screenController.addNewScreen(screen);
            }else{
                System.out.println("else if data is calid");
                String hashPassword = user.md5Java(passWord);
                hashPassword = "e86e107b113b0f830b9b817b4a9addb8";
                user_.setUserName(userName);
                user_.setPassword(passWord);

                System.out.println("Check data availability");
                try 
                {    
                     FileConnection fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open(utilNew.FOLDER_LOCATION);
                     FileConnection fc1 = (FileConnection)Connector.open(utilNew.FOLDER_LOCATION_REF);
                     if (!fc.exists())
                     {
                         fc.mkdir(); 
                         if (!fc1.exists())
                         {
                             fc.mkdir(); 
                         }
                     }
                     fc.close();
                 }
                 catch (IOException ioe) 
                 {
                    System.out.println(ioe.getMessage() );
                 }

                if((record.isDataAvailable(record.userTable)==true))
                {
                    System.out.println(">>>>@@@ -1 ");
                    String[] allRecords = record.getAllRecords(record.userTable);
                    boolean proceedYes = true;
                    int count = 0;
                    while(proceedYes && count<allRecords.length)
                    {
                        System.out.println(">>>> Record = " + allRecords[count]);
                        //Dialog.alert(">>>> Record = " + allRecords[count]);
                        DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(allRecords[count].getBytes()));
                        try {
                            System.out.println(">>>>555");
                            //System.out.println(">>>>" + is.readUTF() + " && " + is.readUTF() + " && " + is.readUTF());
                            String l = is.readUTF();
                            String u = is.readUTF();
                            String p = is.readUTF();
                            //System.out.println("e>>>>" + is.readUTF() + " && " + is.readUTF() + " && " + is.readUTF());
                            System.out.println("f>>>>" + l + " && " + u + " && " + p);
                            System.out.println("g>>>>" + userName + " && " + passWord + " && " + p);
                            if(u.equals(userName) && p.equals(passWord))
                            {
                                //Dialog.alert(">>>>12");
                                System.out.println(">>>889948444>");

                                proceedYes = false;

                                MenuLists screen = new MenuLists(10);
                                //UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(homeScreen);
                                ScreenController screenController = ScreenController.getInstance();
                                screenController.setCurrentScreen(SignIn.this);
                                screenController.addNewScreen(screen);
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            System.out.println(">>>>Error " + e.getMessage() + " && " + e.toString() );
                        }
                        count++;
                    }



                    if(proceedYes)
                    {

                        System.out.println(">>>>@@@ 3 ");
                        Hashtable jj = new Hashtable();
                        boolean proceedNow = false;

                        jj.put("username", userName);
                        jj.put("password", passWord);
                        jj.put("url", "https://localhost:8080/signinws/rest/account/login2");
                        System.out.println("object sent to server: "+jj);


                        ProcessAction processAction = new ProcessAction(jj, 0, record);
                        PopUpScreen.showScreenAndWait(processAction, "Setting up our account. Please Wait");


                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    System.out.println(">>>>@@@ o ");
                    Hashtable jj = new Hashtable();
                    boolean proceedNow=false;

                    System.out.println(">>>>@@@ 4 ");
                    jj.put("username", userName);
                    jj.put("password", passWord);
                    jj.put("url", "https://localhost:8080/signinws/rest/account/login2");

                    System.out.println("object sent to server: "+jj);
                    proceedNow = true;
                    ProcessAction processAction = new ProcessAction(jj, 0, record);
                    PopUpScreen.showScreenAndWait(processAction, "Please Wait");

                }

            }
            return super.navigationClick(status, time);
        }
    };


    final LabelField registerButton = new LabelField("", Field.FOCUSABLE)
    {

        public boolean isFocusable() {
            return true;
        }

        protected void drawFocus(Graphics g, boolean on){
            XYRect rect = new XYRect();
            getFocusRect(rect);
            drawHighlightRegion(g, HIGHLIGHT_FOCUS, false, rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
        }


        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            EncodedImage left;
            EncodedImage right;
            EncodedImage center;
            int hColor;

            if(isFocus())
            {
                left = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("img/buttons/left.png");
                center = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("img/buttons/center.png");
                right = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("img/buttons/right.png");
                g.setColor(util.green);
                hColor = 0xcccccc;
            }
            else
            {
                left = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("img/buttons/_left.png");
                center = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("img/buttons/_center.png");
                right = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("img/buttons/_right.png");
                g.setColor(util.greenDark);
                hColor = util.ashbrand;
            }
            //g.fillRect(0, 0, getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
            int totalWidth = whiteBgWidth + 4;
            XYRect left_edge=new XYRect(2, 2, left.getWidth(), left.getHeight());

            g.drawBitmap(left_edge, left.getBitmap(), 0, 0);
            //invalidate();
            int startX= (Display.getWidth() - totalWidth)/2;
            int vount = (int)((totalWidth - left.getWidth() - right.getWidth())/center.getWidth()) - 3;
            XYRect left_edgeH=new XYRect(0, 0, vount, left.getHeight()+2);
            //System.out.println("vount = " + vount);
            int widthbt = 0;
            for(int c=0; c<vount; c++)
            {
                widthbt = left.getWidth() + (c*center.getWidth()) + 2;
                XYRect center_edge=new XYRect(widthbt, 2, center.getWidth(), center.getHeight());
                g.drawBitmap(center_edge, center.getBitmap(), 0, 0);
            }
            XYRect right_edge=new XYRect(widthbt,2, right.getWidth(), right.getHeight());
            g.drawBitmap(right_edge, right.getBitmap(), 0, 0);
            //invalidate();
            //g.drawBitmap(right_edge, right.getBitmap(), 0, 0);
            //g.fillRect(left_edge.getWidth(), 0, getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
            int colorOld = g.getColor();
            g.setColor(hColor);
            g.drawRoundRect(0, 0, totalWidth-4, left.getHeight()+4, 3, 3);
            g.setColor(colorOld);

            if(isFocus())
            {
                g.setColor(util.black);
            }
            else
            {
                g.setColor(util.whitebrand);
            }

            int height = (left.getHeight() - getFont().getHeight())/2;
            int width = (totalWidth - getFont().getAdvance("Create An Account"))/2;
            g.drawText("Create An Account", width, height);
            setExtent(totalWidth + 5,left.getHeight() + 10);
            setPosition(0, getFont().getHeight() + 30);
            invalidate();
            super.paint(g);
        }

        public int getPreferredHeight() {
            return getFont().getHeight() + 20;
        }

        public int getPreferredWidth() {
            return (int)(whiteBgWidth);
        }

        protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
            removeAllMenuItems();
            RegisterScreen registerScreen = new RegisterScreen();
            ScreenController screenController = ScreenController.getInstance();
            screenController.addNewScreen(registerScreen);
            return super.navigationClick(status, time);
        }
    };


    final VerticalFieldManager spaceHolder2 = new VerticalFieldManager(NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL)
    {
        public void paint(Graphics graphics)
        {
            graphics.setBackgroundColor(utilNew.ashbrand);
            graphics.clear();
            super.paint(graphics);
        }


        public void sublayout(int width, int height){
            int w = whiteBgWidth;
            super.sublayout(w, (loginButton.getPreferredHeight() * 2) + 40);
            setExtent(w, (loginButton.getPreferredHeight() * 2) + 40);
            int startX = (int)((Display.getWidth() - whiteBgWidth)/2);
            setMargin(new XYEdges(20, 0, 0, startX));
        }
    };
    spaceHolder2.add(loginButton);
    spaceHolder2.add(registerButton);
    //spaceHolder2.add(registerButton);


    spaceHolder1.add(contentHolderPix);
    everythingPanel.add(spaceHolder1);
    contentHolder1.add(usernameFieldHolder);
    contentHolder1.add(passwordFieldHolder);





    /*passwordFieldDummyHolder.setFocusListener(new FocusChangeListener(){

        public void focusChanged(Field field, int eventType) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(eventType == FocusChangeListener.FOCUS_GAINED)
            {
                contentHolder1.replace(passwordFieldDummyHolder, passwordFieldHolder);
            }
        }

    });

    passwordFieldHolder.setFocusListener(new FocusChangeListener(){

        public void focusChanged(Field field, int eventType) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(eventType == FocusChangeListener.FOCUS_LOST)
            {
                System.out.println(">>>>>|>>>" + passwordFieldHolder.getIndex());
                System.out.println(">>>>>|>>>" + passwordFieldDummyHolder.getIndex());
                if(passwordField.getText().length()==0)
                {
                    System.out.println(">>>>>1>>>");
                    passwordFieldDummyHolder = utilNew.generateEditTextField(passwordFieldDummy, true, holderPad2, edHt, edWt, false);
                    contentHolder1.replace(passwordFieldHolder, passwordFieldDummyHolder);
                    //loginButton.setFocus();
                }
                System.out.println(">>>>>2>>>");
                System.out.println(">>>>>2>>>");
            }
        }


    });*/





    everythingPanel.add(contentHolder1);
    everythingPanel.add(spaceHolder2);
    add(everythingPanel);


}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the device giving you problems is the Porsche 9981?  Can you also confirm that you have downloaded the 9981 Simulator and tested using that?

Comment: @PeterStrange Yes I have confirmed that its a Porsche 9981. I also had to download the Simulator from blackberrys developer site in order to verify if it was behaving like that on the simulator. It works well on the simulator :(

Comment: OK.  I have never seen this sort of issue, but then I seldom use paint() in a Manager except to create a background.  Can I suggest then that you create a small sample that demonstrates the problem and post the code.  One other thing, does it also fail in a real 9900 - which is basically the same device as the 9981?

Comment: This would happen as the device tries to optimize the screen redrawing. One simple hack would be to call `Screen.invalidate()` on scroll by implementing a `ScrollChangeListener`. However, you should ideally override `paintBackground()` instead of `paint()` method or use the `Border` and `Background` classes (5.0 and onwards)

Comment: @PeterStrange I do not have a 9900 so I dont know if it fails on a 9900. Again it works perfectly well on the 9981 simulator.
I have added sample code of a screen shot which I am experiencing breakages in the design and poor rendering of the screen. The same issue is what I am experiencing in the rest of the screens. Was wondering if I opted to use OpenGL, if it may solve my problem since I read that the 9981 screen technology is a bit different from the normal BB screens. Thanks for your response and sorry I couldnt reply quickly.

Comment: @adwiv
Thanks for your advice. I would try what you have suggested though I can remember reading that its not advisable to override paintBackground() rather overriding paint() seems to be the usual solution.
As for the invalidate(), yes I do have that on some screens but the screens do not even render the EditFields and other items properly in the first place before considering the scrolling effect. I will implement your advice and see if it solves the problem. Thanks

Comment: @OnyekachiAkujua paintBackground() is not recommended only because its an undocumented method. Now that BB Java API is not going to be developed further, there is nothing to worry.

Comment: Some other unrelated suggestions - Do not use `EncodedImage.getEncodedImage()` and `image.getBitmap()` methods within the paint method. There methods are very processing intensive there is no need to do them at each paint. Instead, take them out into static fields. Only use the reference to the Bitmap within the paint method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your problem actually is, but from what I have seen in your sample code it is clear that you are using the UI framework in a way that is not correct.  You need to fix these issues before proceeding further.

Here is an example:

```
final VerticalFieldManager everythingPanel = new VerticalFieldManager(VERTICAL_SCROLL)
    {
        public void paint(Graphics graphics)
        {
            graphics.setBackgroundColor(new UtilNew().ashbrand);
            graphics.clear();
            super.paint(graphics);
        }
        public void sublayout(int width, int height){

            super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight());
            setExtent(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
        }
    };
```

In this case you ask the parent Manager to lay itself out and give it specific sizes to do so.  When doing this, you need to be sure that the sizes you are giving the parent class are not bigger than the size you have been given,  So it is more correct to code something like:

```
super.sublayout(Math.min(Display.getWidth(), width),Math.min(Display.getHeight(), height));
```

What this will do is attempt to layout the Fields that are contained in the Manager, within the confines of the screen space you have told it to use (in this case the size of the screen).  Having done this, it will set the actual size that it needs - in other words, at the end of the layout method, VerticalFieldManager will know how big it needs to be and will set that size.  Then it returns.  And then you do this:

```
setExtent(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
```

Effectively now you have a VerticalFieldManager that thinks it is working in a certain size, and will optimise its painting around that size, and you have potentially given it a different size.  This could confuse!

The same comments apply within a Field's layout() method too.

In other words, if you are going to let the super class layout the Fields, then let the super class set the size, otherwise things can be confused.

Here is another, in fact worse, example:

```
   final VerticalFieldManager spaceHolder2 = new VerticalFieldManager(NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL)
    {
        public void paint(Graphics graphics)
        {
            graphics.setBackgroundColor(utilNew.ashbrand);
            graphics.clear();
            super.paint(graphics);
        }


        public void sublayout(int width, int height){
            int w = whiteBgWidth;
            super.sublayout(w, (loginButton.getPreferredHeight() * 2) + 40);
            setExtent(w, (loginButton.getPreferredHeight() * 2) + 40);
            int startX = (int)((Display.getWidth() - whiteBgWidth)/2);
            setMargin(new XYEdges(20, 0, 0, startX));
        }
    };
```

Why is this worse?  Because of this line:

```
setMargin(new XYEdges(20, 0, 0, startX));
```

Remember the point of sublayout is to position all your Fields on the screen.  You have invoked the super.sublayout() processing to do this, and then, once it has done it, you suddenly say actually, I want some margins on the Field. Again you are potentially confusing the processing - in the middle of laying out the Fields you are changing one of the factors that is related to laying the Fields out...

I suggest you review the documentation around creating Managers (and presumably Fields) and look to remove any code that is disrupting this process.  To assist you in this investigation, I recommend that you start here:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/MainScreen-explained/ta-p/606644

and then look at these:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-Extend-the-Screen/ta-p/446745

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-Extend-the-Screen/ta-p/446745

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-a-custom-layout-manager-for-a-screen/ta-p/442990

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-custom-fields/ta-p/444962

You do a similar sort of thing in your paint routine.  Here is a snippet:

```
            public void paint(Graphics g)
            {
                EncodedImage left;
                EncodedImage right;   
...
               left = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("img/buttons/left.png");
...
                setExtent(totalWidth + 5,left.getHeight() + 10);
                setPosition(0, getFont().getHeight() + 30);
                invalidate();
                super.paint(g);
            }
```

paint()'s job is to paint, not to position.  Your code is supposed to position Fields in your layout (or sublayout) processing.  But in the code above, you potentially move and change the size of a Field while it is trying to paint it!!!!  This is bound to cause the system some problems.

The general rule in paint() is you do NOT change the Field, you just paint its current contents.

Two other things I will comment on with respect to the paint() code given above.

1) paint() is called often.  You really want to minimise the processing done in paint.  So don't create an image (see the left image in the code included above) each time you go through it.  Create this once and then use paint to paint() the image.  Doing excessive work in paint causes performance problems as well as killing the battery. This is the sort of thing you will not notice on the Simulator because it is so fast compared to the device.

2) And be aware that idea when using invalidate() is to repaint the Field.  So there is no point calling invalidate() in the middle of paint().  In fact by doing this, you are causing an infinite loop.  Each time you call paint(), your code is then using invalidate() to ask the Field to repaint itself, which causes paint() to be invoked, which asks for a invalidate(), ...  You get the picture!.

I have pointed out problems in your layout processing and your paint processing.  I'm not saying that these problems are in fact directly giving you the issues you see.  It might be something else.  You have supplied far too much code for me to review it all looking for that needle.  If you want us to review code in detail, then I suggest you recreate the problem with a smaller sample of code.  In fact I recommend you try to do this, because by cutting out code until the problem disappears, you will find out what actually is causing the problem.

Finally a couple of other points:

A) There is no real difference between doing background painting in paint() or paintBackground().  And in fact the only background painting you seem to do is this:

```
        graphics.setBackgroundColor(new UtilNew().ashbrand);
        graphics.clear();
```

which is absolutely fine in paint(), and I wouldn't bother changing this to use paintBackground() or a Background class.  The one issue I have with this code is that fact that you create a new class instance of UtilNew each time paint is invoked (which is a lot).  That won't help performance.

B) I would avoid calling Screen.invalidate() in a scroll change listener until you are sure that there is no other way to get the screen painted correctly. As noted, there is a lot of other suspect code in what you have supplied.  Correct that before you try Screen.invalidate().